# force:inputField erroring out. Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

```
   <aura:attribute name="cObj" access="global" type="Case" default="{'sObjectType':'Case'}"/>

                        <force:inputField aura:id="reqType" value="{!v.cObj.Type}"></force:inputField>
```

I get this error when loading this app with this component.

Aura.loadComponent(): Failed to initialize application.

Deleting the force:inputfield makes the page load properly.

Confused about why this doesn't seem to work at all for me. Doesn't matter what field I tried. Read the api and done other research, seeing if i'm missing some syntax or something obvious and couldn't find the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

So, the issue is not the spacing. `JSON` doesn't care about spacing.

The issue is that you have used `sObjectType` rather than `sobjectType`

Change

```
default="{ 'sObjectType': 'Case' }"
```

To:

```
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case' }"
```

Notice the capitalization change?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your default value for the attribute 'cObj'. the spacing inside curly braces is not there in your attribute thats what is breaking

```
default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case' }"
```

Comment: I copied pasted that. doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: Maybe copy paste is the issue. Can you manually type it

Comment: yep. still an issue. also it should be sObjectType right?

Comment: and its not affecting any of my other ui inputfields that call cObj

Answer (score 0):

Just try the same as below:

```
<aura:attribute name="cObj" type="Case" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case' }"/>
<force:inputField aura:id="reqType" value="{!v.cObj.Type}"/>
```